# generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options stopped generating .h files

Tags: catkin, dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So far I had no problems building our project. I'm sure I built it successfully containing several `_gencfg targets`. Now, suddenly, with no obvious reason, `catkin_make` fails on all `_gencfg` targets. The only thing that's changed is I did `apt-get upgrade`, but I don't think it touched any ROS-related packages.

We're using Indigo on 14.04. The .cfg files have the executable bit set.

After running `catkin_make` and receiving the error, I look into `/home/peckama2/tradr-git/tradr-ws/devel/include/optris_camera/`, and the .h file has not been generated.

Here is the compile log (shortened):

```
$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/peckama2/tradr-git/tradr-ws
Source space: /home/peckama2/tradr-git/tradr-ws/src
Build space: /home/peckama2/tradr-git/tradr-ws/build
Devel space: /home/peckama2/tradr-git/tradr-ws/devel
Install space: /home/peckama2/tradr-git/tradr-ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/peckama2/tradr-git/tradr-ws/build"
####
####
#### Running command: "make -j4 -l4" in "/home/peckama2/tradr-git/tradr-ws/build"
####
... shortened ...
[  1%] [  1%] Built target std_srvs_generate_messages_py
Generating dynamic reconfigure files from cfg/camera_nodelet_params.cfg: /home/peckama2/tradr-git/tradr-ws/devel/include/optris_camera/camera_nodelet_paramsConfig.h /home/peckama2/tradr-git/tradr-ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/optris_camera/cfg/camera_nodelet_paramsConfig.py
: Directory or file does not exist
make[2]: *** [/home/peckama2/tradr-git/tradr-ws/devel/include/optris_camera/camera_nodelet_paramsConfig.h] Error 127
make[1]: *** [tradr-payload/optris_camera/CMakeFiles/optris_camera_gencfg.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Built target std_srvs_generate_messages_lisp
[  1%] [  1%] Built target std_srvs_generate_messages_cpp
Built target _optris_camera_generate_messages_check_deps_AutoFlag
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make" failed
```

The .cfg file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

PACKAGE='optris_camera'
#import roslib
#roslib.load_manifest(PACKAGE)

from dynamic_reconfigure.parameter_generator_catkin import *

gen = ParameterGenerator()
# Name Type Level Description Default Min Max
gen.add("frame_id", str_t, 0, "Camera frame ID.", "thermo_camera")
gen.add("framerate", int_t, 0, "Camera frame rate. [Hz]", 10, 1, 120)
gen.add("recali_time", int_t, 0, "Time for recalibration of camera. [s]", 0, 0, 120)
gen.add("timestamp_offset", double_t, 0, "Camera timestamp offset. [s]", 0, -2, 2)
gen.add("use_ros_time", bool_t, 0, "Switch between ros time and time monotonic.", False)
exit(gen.generate(PACKAGE, "optris_camera", "camera_nodelet_params"))
```

And an excerpt from CMakeLists.txt (comments and some unnecessary code removed):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(optris_camera)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
roscpp
std_msgs
std_srvs
sensor_msgs
image_transport
message_generation
camera_info_manager
nodelet
dynamic_reconfigure
)

generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options(
cfg/camera_nodelet_params.cfg)

catkin_package(
INCLUDE_DIRS
include
LIBRARIES
optris_camera_nodelets
CATKIN_DEPENDS
roscpp
std_msgs
std_srvs
sensor_msgs
image_transport
message_runtime
camera_info_manager
nodelet
DEPENDS
libudev-dev
Boost
)

include_directories(include)

add_executable(thermo_node src/thermo_node.cpp src/camera.cpp src/error.cpp)
add_executable(thermo_colorconvert_node src/thermo_colorconvert_node.cpp)
add_library(optris_camera_nodelets src/thermo_processing_nodelet.cpp src/error.cpp)

## Specify libraries to link a library or executable target against
target_link_libraries(
thermo_node
Imager
ImageProcessing
udev
${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)

add_dependencies(thermo_node ${PROJECT_NAME}_gencfg ${PROJECT_NAME}_generate_messages_cpp)

target_link_libraries(
thermo_colorconvert_node
PIImager
PIImageProcessing
${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)

target_link_libraries(
optris_camera_nodelets
${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)
```

Thanks for any help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195512/generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options-stopped-generating-.h-files/) by [peci1](https://answers.ros.org/users/7736/peci1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1366 on 2014-10-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-10-21**:
Is it possible that it's complaining about python itself being missing for some reason? What do you get if you run `/usb/bin/env python` ?

**Comment by [peci1](https://answers.ros.org/users/7736/peci1/) on 2014-10-21**:
That was also my try, but when I run the command after shebang, I get a normal python console.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-10-21**:
Please try it with a minimal CMakeLists.txt file:

```
project(optris_camera)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS dynamic_reconfigure)
generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options(cfg/camera_nodelet_params.cfg)
catkin_package()
```

This works fine for me.

**Comment by [peci1](https://answers.ros.org/users/7736/peci1/) on 2014-10-21**:
Same result :( What could go wrong?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-10-21**:
Please post your version number of dynamic_reconfigure. Also consider putting your minimal package in a GitHub repo to share - may be something is wrong which is not obvious from your posted code.

**Comment by [peci1](https://answers.ros.org/users/7736/peci1/) on 2014-10-22**:
ros-inidigo-dynamic-reconfigure 1.5.37-0trusty-20140905-0110-+0000

**Comment by [peci1](https://answers.ros.org/users/7736/peci1/) on 2014-10-22**:
I've created a whole new catkin workspace to test this thing. I've properly sourced its setup.bash, and the problem is the same. Here is the minimal workspace with the buildfiles included: https://app.box.com/s/af4foufx341jfk6rlzjz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Got it! The problem was in CRLF (Windows) line-ending that somehow propagated to my cfg files.

I use ROS virtualized under Windows and the sources dir is a shared folder, so maybe Windows did something odd to the files.

And the message about file or dir not existing was really about the interpreter - the system tried to launch `/usr/bin/env python<CR>`, which obviously does not exist.

Thanks to all for your help.

---

Originally posted by [peci1](https://answers.ros.org/users/7736/peci1/) with karma: 1366 on 2014-10-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0